# Change order of selects in Symfony2 datetime Field Type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Im using Symfony2. I am displaying 3 `<select>` to chose a birth date:

```
$dobOptions = array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'years'  => range($date["year"]-100, $date["year"]-18),
    'empty_value' => array(
        'year'  => 'Year',
        'month' => 'Month',
        'day'   => 'Day'));
$builder->add('dob', 'date', $dobOptions)
```

The problem here is that is shows first the year, then the month, and finally the day. I would like to turn the order of the form elements the other way around. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the doc, if you chose the choice widget, you can specify the order of the selects with the format option. It would give you something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    // other options
);
```

Comment: I thought that would only would work with single_text wudgets! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the format option http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#format

```
$dobOptions = array(
'input'  => 'datetime',
'widget' => 'choice',
'years'  => range($date["year"]-100, $date["year"]-18),
'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'
'empty_value' => array(
    'year'  => 'Year',
    'month' => 'Month',
    'day'   => 'Day'));
```